# Запуск программы с графическим интерфейсом через ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

Имеется следующая задача:

2 ПК, на обоих установлен AstraLinux SE

1.Необходимо создать скрипт который запускается на ПК клиента.

2.Данный скрипт должен выполнить подключение по ssh к другому ПК и на этом втором ПК запустить программу(оконное приложение).

3.После этого ПК клиента можно выключить или просто выполнить отключение от ssh сессии. При этом запущенная программа должна продолжить работать.

Проблема в том что при выполнении 3 пункта, запущенная программа(будь то хоть kate хоть любая другая) также отключается.

В интернете куча советов по использованию screen, tmux, nohup, disown и т.д. но ни один не помог. При отключении от ssh (exit или logout), запущенная программа выключается.

Возникает вопрос возможно ли вообще такое сделать или обойти завершение всех запущенных процессов по ssh при его отключении в принципе нельзя??

Comment: Почему "ни один не помог"?

Comment: systemd в астре есть?

Comment: @eri да, systemd есть. /bin/systemd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создай юнит ~/.config/systemd/user/gedit.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gedit

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment="XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000"
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gedit
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

Запускай

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 systemctl --user start gedit.service
```

Процесс будет запущен не из сессии SSH, а из сессии пользователя через супервизор.

Лог

```
journalctl --user -u gedit.service -e -f
```

Comment: Когда DISPLAY случайно окажется 1, будет ой. Неужели линукс-сообщество так до сих пор и не придумало, как такое нормально обрабатывать? Хотя бы записывать актуальный номер где-нибудь рядом с ~/.Xauthority что ли...

Comment: "окажется 1" - тут для ручного запуска, вручную поправит ;) посмотрит команду `who`

Comment: @eri я не совсем опытный пользователь linux. можно чуть по подробней. где именно нужно создать данный файл? на пк клиента или сервера? когда запускать команду ниже? после подключения по ssh? после её выполнения нужно запускать нужную мне программу?

Comment: там где запускаешь. когда захочешь, по ссх. эта команда запустит прописанную в сервисе команду

Comment: @eri Предварительно пришлось создать каталоги /systemd/user/ так как по указанному пути их не было. вместо gedit в ExecStart написал kate для проверки. В любом случае при запуске последней команды вывело: Failed to start _kate.service: Unit _kate.service not found.
 
Продолжу завтра пробовать дальше.

Comment: попробуй без нижнего подчеркивания. посмотри лог

Comment: @eri Спасибо за пример. Без нижнего подчёркивания получилось запустить